# Captcha with Multipart Form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, captcha

I have a multipart form that I need a captcha for at the end. Essentially, a user is allowed to create/update a draft but not submit it for admin review until everything is done. There is a captcha meant for the last submission but the problem is that when I add it to the form, I can't use any of the other submit buttons because the captcha isn't filled out. Is there any way around this?

I'm using `simple_captcha` and Rails 3.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used simple_captcha before, but seems like you are doing `@object.save_with_captcha` in every case. You have multiple options to solve this, but one i came up with is:

In the controller, verify if all the fields (mandatory only i guess) are filled, and if they are, then save your object using `@object.save_with_captcha`, otherwise do the usual `@object.save` which wont trigger the captcha validation. Something like this:

```
def create  
  @object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])  
  if @object.has_mandatory_fields_filled?  
    @object.save_with_captcha  
  else  
    @object.save  
  end  
end
```

In the has_mandatory_fields_filled? method you would check that all the mandatory fields of your form are not empty/nil etc.